# The electric field from an infinite plate without using Gauss's law

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Using Gauss's law it is quite straightforward, but how to do it without using it? My idea is to calculate the potential $$V(r)=\int \frac{\sigma }{r}da$$ and then calculate the gradient, but I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also derive the expression for the electric field due to a circular plate by integrating the expression for an electric field due to a circular ring (which is straightforward to derive) from $0$ to $R$ and then setting $R=\infty $.

Comment: @KarolBorkowski Yes this is how to proceed.  Computing the potential first will not work since there are charges at $\infty$, which makes your expression for $V(r)$ invalid.